# Unable to load data for nested table dynamically

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I have created a table using component `nztable` from ``ng-zorro`. That table contains a nested table where I want to load data dynamically(REST service call) on click of the expand icon.

I am able to load the data in the nested table but when I expand next row, it is overriding data in the first row with the new result.

As nested table creation is in the loop(ngfor), I am unable to control the data binding to a specific row.

```
<nz-table #nestedTable [nzData]="displayData" [nzPageSize]="10">
    <thead colspan="5">
    <tr>
      <th nzWidth="4%"nzShowExpand></th>
      <th nzWidth="12%">Id</th>
      <th nzWidth="10%">Start Time</th>
      <th nzWidth="10%">End Time</th>
      <th nzWidth="10%">Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <ng-template ngFor let-data [ngForOf]="nestedTable.data">
      <tr>
        <td nzShowExpand [(nzExpand)]="data.expand" (click)="getDetails(data)"></td>
        <td >{{data.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{data.startTime}}</td>
        <td>{{data.endTime}}</td>
        <td>{{data.status}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr [nzExpand]="data.expand">
        <td><nz-spin  *ngIf="isEventLoading"></nz-spin></td>
        <td colspan="9">
          <nz-table #innerTable [nzData]="innerTableData" nzSize="middle" [nzShowPagination]="false">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>E ID</th>
      <th>S ID</th>
      <th>E Type</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of innerTable.data">
      <td>{{data.eID}}</td>
      <td>{{data.sID}}</td>
      <td>{{data.eType}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </nz-table>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some relevant code and error messages if any. In its current form it is unclear what is exactly the issue.

Comment: @suvartheec: There is no error. This issue is related to loading the nested table data dynamically. It is loading the same data to all children.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this `[nzData]="innerTableData"`  whith your inner collection like this `[nzData]="data.childRows"`.